# Convergence to a local minimum of K-means

Tags: convergence-divergence, maxima-minima

I recently sat an exam (Stanford's CS229 on machine learning) and I faced the following question.

> True or False? K-means is guaranteed to converge to a local minimum of the objective $J(c, \mu) = \sum^n_{i=1} \lVert x(i) − \mu_{c(i)} \rVert^2$ in a finite number of iterations.

I answered that this is false because, as the lecture notes point out, although the K-means algorithm is guaranteed to converge in value space $\mathbb R$ (because our data set is finite and $K$, the number of clusterings, is finite), if there are two clusterings $c^*$ and $c'$ that such that $J$ assigns equal value $r$ to each and the value of $J$ (under the action of the algorithm converges to $r$, then the algorithm may oscillate for ever between clustering $c^*$ and $c'$.

Of course, I am here because I was awarded zero marks and everyone else seems to have answered True and got this right.

In my view, the statement would be true if we say that K-means is guaranteed to converge to *a set of local minima* of the objective. Or we said something like the value of the objective is guaranteed to converge. *Convergence to a local minimum of the objective* is only a meaningful statement if we consider the graph of that objective.

Looking for moral support here :)

Comment: The question as I interpret it does not ask about the actual clusters, just the local minimum of the objective function. IIRC K-means is a special case of EM algorithm which can be viewed as coordinate descent, but I don't remember if this is guaranteed to converge after finitely many steps.

Comment: Yeah, but what do we mean when we say a local min of the objective function: we mean in the graph sense, not just the value. Mathematically (see wikipedia), we refer to the graph. We do the same for other algorithms such as Expectation Maximisation where the arguments to the objective are in $\mathbb R^d$. (Here we are effectively in a discrete and finite space because there are only finitely many ways to compute the mean given a finite set of data. If the statement refers to values only, then every point is a local minimum and a local maximum. It's "local" that forces us to think of domain.)

Comment: The minimum of the objective is different than the argmin. Regardless the question is a little vague.

Comment: @qwr agreed, but, as the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_and_minimum attests, we speak of the "(local) minimum points of a function" as members of the domain. The point is that we don't necessarily speak of argmins when referring to the domain. In this regard, I agree the question is vague. But in any normal mathematical discourse, if you were to say "J has converged to a local minimum", I think we all agree that you mean a point $(x, J(x))$ such that for $y$ in a neighbourhood of $x$, $J(y) \geq J(x)$. In this case, I claim the statement is false.

Comment: Any way, the lecturer, Anand Avanti, saw the light and gave me my marks, so I'm happy now. I just hope this relative scheme for awarding A-F doesn't leave me on the wrong side of a grade boundary. After all, everyone else should have got this wrong! This is why absolute grade boundaries that are clear upfront create better incentives for learning.